# Problem with cascade validation in Spring Boot (rest)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Rest-method:

```
@NewSpan("NewSpan")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponceEntity someRest(@Valid @RequestBody RestBody) {}
```

Rest body structure:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_table")
public class RestBody implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @NotNull(message = "Errr txt")
   String id;
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   SomeStatus status;
   @NotNull(message = "Errr txt")
   @Valid
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   List<ChildElement> childElements;
}


@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_table")
public class ChildElement implements Serializable {

   @NotNull(message = "Errr txt")
   String name;
   @NotNull(message = "Errr txt")
   @Convert(converter = JsonNodeConverter.class)
   @Column(name = "content_schema", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
   JsonNode extContent;
}
```

`Spring` validate fields in `RestBody`, but ignore it in `ChildElement`. (like example when "name" is null).

**How to configure Spring or classes to validate child elements?**

P.S. If I try validate it with `ValidatorImpl` manually, it check and `RestBody`, and `ChildElement`.
P.P.S. Spring Boot - 2.1.6

Comment: Empty name or `null` name are different cases.

Comment: Do you have the spring-boot-starter-validation dependency included

Comment: @M.Deinum I mean null (fix info in question).

Comment: @Simon Martinelli No, I haven't. I will try it later.

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim    check the import for NotNull. It should be javax.validation.constraints.NotNull

Comment: Without spring-boot-starter-validation  it will not work!

Answer (score 0):

Try with `@NotBlank` instead of `@NotNull` because maybe your client app is sending those values an non-null values
Especially when your code and validation annotation looks okay.

Comment: I found it in unitests, and check RestBody in debug.

Answer (score -1):

You have to include

```
spring-boot-starter-validation
```

as dependency to make this run.